# React Hooks State is not updated the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Setting the state and the function which is updating the state:

```
const [objectivesOpen, setObjectivesOpen] = useState([]);
const toggleObjectives = () => {
  console.log('objectivesOpenNotUpdated', objectivesOpen);
  setObjectivesOpen([Math.random()]);
}
```

Calling the function:

```
<button onClick={toggleObjectives}>Test</button>
```

objectivesOpen is not getting the updated value after clicking the button the next time.

UPDATE:
The value is updated in useEffect(), but not when clicking the button.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('objectivesOpen in effect', objectivesOpen);
});

const toggleObjectives = () => {
  console.log('time:', new Date())
  console.log('objectivesOpen', objectivesOpen);

  setObjectivesOpen([Math.random()]);
};
```

Results:

```
time: Thu Dec 03 2020 17:17:58 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
objectivesOpen [0.4735904311779686]
objectivesOpen in effect [0.12100479433701583]
time: Thu Dec 03 2020 17:18:01 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
objectivesOpen [0.4735904311779686]
objectivesOpen in effect [0.6376121961469396]
```

Comment: The `useEffect` logs are really strange. They suggest there is some `ref` or `memo` being used between the definition of the `toggleObjectives()` function and the render of the `<button>`.

Comment: What happens if you do a simple `console.log` of objectivesOpen (remove the surrounding useEffect)?

Comment: Here is a codepen with different types of logs: https://codepen.io/wintvelt/pen/MWjKeEY?editors=0011
they show the expected (correct) behaviour.

Comment: @wintvelt Thanks for the demo! It's strange, because it works correctly as it should on your demo. But in my app, what I needed to do to get the current value in the function is: `setObjectivesOpen((currState) => {
      console.log('objectivesOpen in setObjectivesOpen', currState);
      return [Math.random()];
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log inside the `toggleObjectives` can be confusing: that is in the middle of an update. What that log does is show you the current or old value, just before you change the value. So you only get to see the value AFTER you click "Change", but BEFORE the change is fully processed.

If you want to know the value of the `objectivesOpen`, I would advise to put the console log directly below the useState command. That is a more logical place.

Like so:

```js
const [objectivesOpen, setObjectivesOpen] = useState([]);
console.log('objectivesOpen = ', objectivesOpen);

const toggleObjectives = () => {
  setObjectivesOpen([Math.random()]);
}
```

Then you get the value of `objectivesOpen` after each render.
This is the value that is used in later code, e.g. if you want to display the `objectivesOpen` value to the user in a component.

If you put it here, you will get first `[]`, the initial empty value.
And then after each click, you get a new console log with the new value AFTER the state has been updated..

Maybe it is helpful to explain the what your code does.

- On the first run, the value of `objectivesOpen` will be an empty array (`[]`), based on the first time you call `useState([])`
- When the user clicks the function `toggleObjectivesOpen()`, the console should log this empty array
- Then the asynchronous `setObjectiveOpen()` is called, passing in a new value of `[Math.random()]` (let's assume the value is `[0.25]`
- It is possible that the user clicks the button again, before the state is updated. If that happens, the console should again show the old `[]` value of the state.
- Or, if the user clicks after the state is updated, then the console shows the
  value after the first update (`[0.25]` from the example above).
- After the state is updated, the code in the component will be run again. React will then ignore the `useState` command. But it will run the rest of the code (including all console.logs) and render all (child) components again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The thing is that you want to have the new updated value in the function, because you want to grab the current value -> do something to that value -> update that value.

Comment: Yes, you can use the current value. And do something to that value. But you will not see the new value. So whatever is showing in your console, is always outdated: you log the old value, then change value, then wait until user clicks again. But until the user clicks, the real value is different from your latest log.. That is really confusing: your log then NEVER shows the current value, is always shows an old value.

Answer (score 4):

`setObjectivesOpen` is the asynchronous method, and you can't get the updated `objectivesOpen` value right immediately after `setObjectivesOpen`.

You should use useEffect with adding an `objectivesOpen` dependency to get an updated `objectivesOpen` value.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('objectivesOpenNotUpdated', objectivesOpen);
}, [objectivesOpen]);
```

Comment: Let's say I'm waiting a couple of seconds until I click the button again. It should give me the updated state in the function right?

Comment: if you call the `toggleObjectives()` method, yes, you can see the updated `objectivesOpen` value.

Comment: e.g. lets say you call the method like this `useEffect(() => { toggleObjectives() }, []` which means the componentDidMount,  you can see the updated value when you click the button later

Comment: Did a test with waiting 3 seconds and it seems the new value is reflected in the useEffect, but not when I call the function again (click the button)

Comment: Any idea what's the reason, why the updated value is not reflected when calling the function again?

Comment: can you update the question how you test with waiting 3 seconds?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Adding `useEffect` complicates the code a lot. If the objective is to log/ use the state value before and after a change, a useEffect hook is not needed.

Comment: it should work. can you attach your code in the stackblitz or codepen? @GregorOjstersek